# Existence of connections making a bundle endomorphism parallel

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

Let $M$ be a manifold, $TM$ its tangent bundle, and $N:TM\to TM$ a vector bundle morphism. It is possible to find a torsionless linear connection $\nabla$ on $TM$ such that $\nabla N=0$?

Comment: The canonical followup question is, of course, what endomorphisms are flat for some connection.

Comment: Actually, I'm interested in a fixed endomorphism $N$, because it is the anchor of a certain Lie algebroid. Rather, a less demanding question would be if there exists a symmetric connection such that $(\nabla_X N)(Y)=(\nabla_Y N)X$ (which is enough for my purposes), but I'm afraid that some integrability conditions will be also required in this case, so I'll try another approach. Anyway, the discussion has been very interesting and helpful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My  answer is almost  contained in the answers/comments  of Mariano Suárez-Alvarez,   Ben McKay  and Robert Bryant; I summarize the answers   and give a reference.

There exists a torsion-free connection such that  a given endomorphism  $A$  is parallel if and only if the following two conditions are fulfilled:
(1) The Jordan type of the endomorphism is the same at all points
(2) The Nijenhujs torsion of the endomorphism vanishes. 
(3) For every k and every eigenvalue $c$  the distribution   $Kern(A-c Id)^k $ is integrable.

A reference  is Thompson, Gerard The integrability of a field of endomorphisms. Math. Bohem. 127 (2002), no. 4, 605–611 and it is downloadable from  https://eudml.org/doc/249030  (actually, this result was reproved and republished  many times, first time possible by  Shirokov in the 50th   who unfortunately published most his works in  obscure places and possibly   the last time by Boubel arXiv:1003.0979)

Comment: If I understand the proof correctly, Thompson's result is local. Let $f(z_1,z_2)=(2z_1,4z_2+z_1^2)$. Let $M=(\mathbb{C}^2-0)/(z \sim f(z))$. A holomorphic affine connection on $M$ is an $f$-invariant holomorphic connection on $\mathbb{C}^2-0$. By Hartog's, such a connection would extend to $\mathbb{C}^2$ which you can check is impossible by taking a Taylor expansion. A torsion-free connection under which the standard complex structure $J$ on $M$ is parallel is holomorphic: $J$ is not parallel under any torsion-free connection, even though it is locally.

Comment: Thompson has  more than one  result in his paper and most probably some  results are local. The answer on the question of Grimolatto I have summarized above is in my understanding global. The  conditions (1,2,3) are geometric and if they are fulfilled locally in a neighborhood of every point than they are fulfilled everywhere, so they are global. Now, if there exists, in a neighborhood of every point, a local  endomorphism-preserving connection, one can glue it into a global connection with the help of the partition of unity (to see this, check that $f \Gamma+ (1-f) \Gamma'$ is a connection)

Comment: OK, my global counterexample is wrong; there is torsion-free connection for which $J$ is parallel, but it is not holomorphic.

Answer (score 4):

No. To be parallel under a connection, $N$ would have to have the same type at each point. In other words, for any two points, there must be a linear map identifying tangent spaces which identifies $N$ at those two tangent spaces. If $N$ vanishes somewhere, it would have to vanish everywhere, for example.

Comment: Suppose then the Jordan type is constant :-)

Comment: That's not enough either.  For example, if $N$ has exactly two eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$ and they are of constant multiplicity, then there will exist a torsion-free connection making $N$ parallel if and only if the two eigenbundles in $TM$ are Frobenius.

Comment: Robert wakes up early.

Comment: Yup, decomposable endomorphisms do not work, but I am having trouble breaking this with one Jordan block.

Comment: But then the generalized eigenspaces are also parallel: $(N-\lambda I)^k=0$. By torsion-freedom, that should make them Frobenius.

Comment: The Nijenhuis tensor of $N$ also has to vanish. (So the notation $N$ is perhaps not ideal here.)